# Can I mark a Twig variable equally as safe as a captured chunk of text?

Tags: string, twig, escaping, twig-filter

Here's a [Twig Fiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/gfi9ih). There you will notice this include file:

```
{# include.twig #}

{{ text }}
```

And this main file, with several attempts to mark a text variable as safe before passing it to the include file:

```
{# main.twig #}

1. Pass string with HTML

{{ include('include.twig', { text: '<p>Text</p>' }) }}


2. Pass string with HTML marked safe with raw filter

{{ include('include.twig', { text: '<p>Text</p>'|raw }) }}


3. Pass variable set with string literal marked safe with raw filter

{% set text = '<p>Text</p>'|raw %}

{{ include('include.twig', { text: text }) }}


4. Pass variable set with captured chunk of text

{% set text %}<p>Text</p>{% endset %} 

{{ include('include.twig', { text: text }) }}
```

And here are the results of rendering this template:

```
1. Pass string with HTML

&lt;p&gt;Text&lt;/p&gt;

2. Pass string with HTML marked safe with raw filter

&lt;p&gt;Text&lt;/p&gt;

3. Pass variable set with string literal marked safe with raw filter

&lt;p&gt;Text&lt;/p&gt;

4. Pass variable set with captured chunk of text

<p>Text</p>
```

The first attempt establishes the unwanted behavior of HTML escaping. Strategies 2 and 3 attempt to use the `|raw` filter to avoid the escaping, but both fail. Strategy 4, using the `set` tag to capture a chunk of text, works perfectly.

The [documentation for the `|raw` filter](http://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html) says:

> The raw filter marks the value as being "safe", which means that in an environment with automatic escaping enabled this variable will not be escaped if raw is the last filter applied to it:

The [documentation for the `set` tag](http://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/set.html) says:

> If you enable automatic output escaping, Twig will only consider the content to be safe when capturing chunks of text.

Unless I'm missing something, these appear to be two different definitions of "safe", with the one mentioned under the `set` tag meaning *super-extra-safe*.

Is there any way to pass *super-extra-safe* HTML-containing string literals into a template, without polluting my file with ugly chunk-capturing `set` blocks?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, you cannot because `twig` does not escape static expression. The `raw` filter is even ignored when compiling the template.

```html
{% set hello = "<strong>Hello</strong>" %}
{% set hello = "<strong>Hello</strong>"|raw %}
```

The two lines above will compile in the same sourcecode

```php
// line 1        
$context["hello"] = "<strong>Hello</strong>";
// line 2
$context["hello"] = "<strong>Hello</strong>";
```

[source](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/autoescape.html)

---

*edit:*

If you really want to do this, you could either write your own include/set node or add a filter which returns a `Twig\Markup`

```php
<?php
    $twig->addFilter(new \Twig\TwigFilter('safe', function($v) {
         return new \Twig\Markup($v);
    });
```

```
{% include 'text.html' with { 'text': 'Hello <strong>World</strong>'|safe, } %}
```

> Hello **World**

Comment: Please help me understand the phrase "Twig does not escape static expressions" and how it applies to this situation. I'm dealing with escaping that *is* happening that I *don't* want to happen, so how is "Escaping *doesn't* happen in this situation" an explanation for it?

Comment: Escaping means that the content is treated as safe, this results in `html` being outputted as real `html` and not as entities (`&lt;strong:&gt;`) I'm not sure why `twig` does not treat literals as safe but that's what they've decided to do

Comment: ...That is not what escaping means. Escaping means turning unsafe characters into safe representations of those characters. I am marking a string as safe, trying to prevent escaping, but am getting escaping anyway. Yet capturing a chunk in a `{% set %}` block, a different way of marking it "safe", *does* prevent escaping. Which is why I think there appears to be two different levels of "safe"ty going on.

Comment: It's litteraly there on the documentation page i've linked as source

Comment: The statement "Twig does not escape static expressions" is true, but it does not apply to my issue, so far as I can tell. And your definition of "escaping" is not what it actually means.

Comment: `I am marking a string as safe` - and this is ignored by the compiler as mentioned in my answer. The only thing you could do is write your own tag that actually makes literals safe

Comment: “Does not escape” means “treats as already safe”. Unsafe strings are escaped, safe ones are not. Yet I have shown that one method of marking safe is escaped, and another method is not. I wish to understand the difference in types of safety, and possibly invoke the stronger one in a different way, or else report this as a Twig bug if it is one.

Comment: Well as I said it's not possible out of the box. Updated my answer with a workaround